# Problemas al intentar actualizar paquetes en linux

Tags: linux

Cuando intento actualizar los paquetes en la distribución de elementary os con el comando

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Se queda cargando indefinidamente en

```
0% [working]
```

Comment: Has comprobado que haya acceso por red a los repositorios configurados en la máquina?

Answer (score 1):

Intenta limpiar la caché y así eliminar todos los paquetes de allí:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

Answer (score 1):

El AppCenter te funciona? o no te baja ningun paquete desde ahi?
Fijate en los repositorios si estan bien, podes editarlos con

```
sudo apt edit-sources
```

tal vez lo mejor sea

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

que de deja tratarlo como si fuera ubuntu

Comment: Gracias me funciono al editar los sources muchas gracias

Answer (score -1):

Prueba con la letra `s` en minúscula:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: El autor de la pregunta indicó que usó `sudo`, en minúscula, pero en los comentarios.